# Displaying interstitial AdMob ad in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, admob, interstitial

I am trying to display ads in my application. The code below is the one I am using now in my `GameViewController.swift`:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import GoogleMobileAds // Network Ads
import AdSupport

class GameViewController: UIViewController, GADBannerViewDelegate, GADInterstitialDelegate {

    var adBannerView: GADBannerView!
    var myAd = GADInterstitial()
    let request = GADRequest()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let scene = GameScene()
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
        scene.size = skView.frame.size
        skView.presentScene(scene)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(GameViewController.loadAndShow), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "loadAndShow"), object: nil)
    }

    func loadAndShow() {
        myAd.setAdUnitID("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910")
        myAd.delegate = self
        myAd.load(request)
    }

    func interstitialDidReceiveAd(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {
        if (self.myAd.isReady) {
            myAd.present(fromRootViewController: self)
        }
    }
}
```

And that code displays this test ad:
[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ODnP.png)

I went into AdMob website and created a "**NEW AD UNIT**" with Ad format: **Interstitial**. Then I got a **Ad unit ID**, but when I put my **Ad unit ID** in the `myAd.setAdUnitID("...")` in my code, it does not shows any ad's in my app at all.

[Click here for image of my AD UNIT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLbto.png)

Any ideas what I've done wrong here?

Comment: Sometimes it takes time after you create an ad unit for it to work properly. After 24 hrs from creation, it should work

Comment: @Nik Yup, looks like that was the reason. All works now.